# Craft CMS GraphQL count query

Tags: craft3, graphql

I've got the GraphQL code posted below, but I'm not sure how do I count the total of returned products .
Do I need another query just for the products without offset ? I need it for a pagination functionality

```
query Products($offset: Int, $priceBetween: [QueryArgument]) {
  products(limit: 9999, orderBy: "dateCreated DESC", offset: $offset, defaultPrice: $priceBetween) {
    id
    defaultPrice
    title
    ... on furniture_Product {
      productThumbnail {
        url @transform(width: 300, immediately: true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [_count](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/1abd40e4fcf1bb01f488447b9d6d392a14d961ac) -- there are some examples here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4847